# I got the following error : error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rename

Tags: c++

im creating a sort of menu/list program using parallel array, functions and switch statements.
this is the error im getting below.

main.cpp:42:23: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rename’?
42 |         getEmpDetails(name, surname, hoursWorked);
|                       ^~~~
|                       rename

the error appears by case 'c'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


// functions 
void menuDisplay();
void getEmpDetails(string[],string[], int[]);


int main()
{
// declaring parrell arrays   
    string name[10]; //for storing Employee names
    string surname[10]; // for storing Employee surname
    int hoursWorked[10]; // for storing employee hours worked
    
    
    //calling the functions
    menuDisplay(); // 
    getEmpDetails(name,surname,hoursWorked); 
    
    return 0;
    
}

void menuDisplay(){
    char choice;
    do{ //this makes the menu repeat itself
        
    cout << "[C]apture Employee details" << endl;
    cout << "[L]ist Employee details" << endl;
    cout << "[A]ll Employee Payslips" << endl;
    cout << "[S]ingle Employee Payslips" << endl;
    cout << "[E]xit" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    
    switch(choice){
        case 'C':
        cout << "capture employee details" << endl;
        getEmpDetails(name, surname, hoursWorked);
        break;
        case 'L':
        cout << "list employee details" << endl;
        break;
        case 'A':
        cout << "All Employee Payslips" << endl;
        break;
        case 'S':
        cout <<"Single employee payslips" << endl;
        break;
        case 'E':
        cout << "Exit" << endl;
        
    }
    
}while(choice == 'C' || choice == 'L' || choice == 'S'|| choice == 'E'|| choice == 'A'); //for selecting the right options on the menu
cout << "invaild choice, please choice either C,L,A,S,E" <<endl; // if the wrong option is selected this appears
}


void getEmpDetails(string name[],string surname[], int hoursWorked[]){
    //this function is for capturing employee details
    for (int x =0; x < 10; x++){
        cout << "enter employee name" <<endl; // geting employee name
        cin >> name[x];
        cout << "enter employee surname" << endl; // getting employee surname
        cin >> surname[x];
        cout << "enter number of hours worked" << endl; // getting hours worked
        cin >> hoursWorked[x];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `menuDisplay` function has no way of knowing what `name`, `surname`, and `hoursWorked` are. You should either pass them as arguments, or make the variables global (which I advise against)

Comment: im not understanding can you elobrate, sorry im a beginner

Comment: Please make every effort to learn about structs/classes soon so you can avoid parallel arrays in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the arrays in `main` but you are trying to use them in `menuDisplay` where they are not declared. That's what the error is saying.

You could pass the arrays to `menuDisplay` as parameters exactly like you have done with `getEmpDetails`.

```
// functions 
void menuDisplay(string[],string[], int[]);
void getEmpDetails(string[],string[], int[]);

int main()
{
// declaring parrell arrays   
    string name[10]; //for storing Employee names
    string surname[10]; // for storing Employee surname
    int hoursWorked[10]; // for storing employee hours worked
    
    
    //calling the functions
    menuDisplay(name,surname,hoursWorked); // 
    getEmpDetails(name,surname,hoursWorked); 
    
    return 0;
    
}

void menuDisplay(string name[],string surname[], int hoursWorked[]){
    ...
}
```